# ClientID inside of ASCX file

Tags: javascript, user-controls, ascx

I am trying to get CLientID inside the  .ascx (user control mark-up) file.

While this

```
My id is: <%=this.ClientID%>
```

renders as
My id is: fracTemplateCtrl

This:

```
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save Template" onclick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return confirmSave('<%=this.ClientID%>');" />
```

renders as (inside Source code):

```
        <input type="submit" name="fracTemplateCtrl$btnSave" value="Save Template" onclick="return confirmSave('&lt;%=this.ClientID%>');" id="fracTemplateCtrl_btnSave" />
```

Clearly, ClientId property does not get evaluated in the second case. How do I overcome this issue? (aside from hardcoding, which is not the answer, I would like to make the user control independent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the OnClientClick property's value server-side like this:

```
btnSave.OnClientClick = "return confirmSave('" + this.ClientID + "')";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save Template" onclick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return confirmSave(this.id);" />
```

Comment: Actually, your first answer got me thinking in the right direction. However, OnClientClick="return confirmSave(this.id);" actually gets evaluated as a button id (not the control id). So you were right the first time.:)

Comment: @gnomixa-Thanks, but the first time I was still wrong.  I was unable to explain it accurately and concisely, so I just threw together code that I thought would work, but by then, I'd forgotten the point!  ;-)  But thanks for the upvote anyway.