# Passing clientId to javascript function from ascx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ascx, clientid

I'm trying to pass my control's client id to java-script function.

But it is giving null all the time.

Below is my code sample.

test.ascx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="mytextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Test"  OnClientClick="javascript:passClientId('<%= mytextbox.ClientID %>');" />
```

Here is my javascript funtion

```
function passClientId(control) {
    var ctrl = document.getElementById(control);
    alert(ctrl);
}
```

In the above function I'm getting control value as '<%= mytextbox.ClientID %>' instead of actual clientid of the control.

How to get it?

Comment: @mplungjan the user needs textbox id...this is get usercontrol id ...iam confused?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675526/clientid-inside-of-ascx-file

Comment: Oops. then `OnClientClick="passClientId(this.previousSibling.id);"` - Note the whitespace in Chrome needs to be bypassed - actually this.previousSibling is the object so no need to use getElementById either

Comment: @mplungjan ..in future user change the control order..then what will happen..

Comment: I dont want to pass button id as parameter. I'm trying to pass my textbox client id as a parameter. And the one what ever you've given as reference as duplicate which is completely different. They are passing button id as parameter and that is quite simple. I'm also able to get it done. But problem with passing text box id.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876751/how-to-access-the-clientid-from-a-servercontrol-in-an-external-javascript

Comment: Can someone provide me any jsfiddle example