# Trying to figure out how to reference my ascx controls from the inline JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, listbox, ascx

I am creating a left-to-right moving listbox control. I have several inline JS functions to handle the moving of list items to and from the left and right listboxes via some buttons (>,<,>>,<<)

In my codebehind, I set the onclick attribute to the appropriate JS function, for ex.

```
btnMoveSelectedItemsToRight.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "AddSelectedItems()");
```

So When I click the button, the JS function is reached, which within it calls another utility JS function which moves the items. The issue is that the function throws and error as it does not recognize the parameters for the MoveSelectedItems as existing. Code:

```
function AddSelectedItems() {
    MoveSelectedItems(lbAvailableCategories, lbChosenCategories);
    UpdateButtonState();
}

 function MoveSelectedItems(srcListBox, dstListBox) {
    srcListBox.BeginUpdate();
    dstListBox.BeginUpdate();
    var items = srcListBox.GetSelectedItems();
    for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var itemText = GetSplitText(items[i].text);
        dstListBox.AddItem(itemText, items[i].value);
        srcListBox.RemoveItem(items[i].index);
    }
    srcListBox.EndUpdate();
    dstListBox.EndUpdate();
}
```

I can tell that I am missing some underlying principal with how to accomplish something like this and am just wondering if anyone can provide some insight

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried with pure html and javascript?

Comment: I can't tell if this is supposed to be javascript or C#...I see C# identifiers and methods but you add things to click instead of client click...are you wanting something that runs purely on the client, or responds to a click and does things on the server in an update panel, or...? I mostly do MVC these days but I think this is web forms so bear with me. I do expect to see a jquery or getElementById or ClientId in here somewhere and don't see one

Comment: When you talk about server controls and javascript running to do things, I was expecting something more like this, where you have a onClientClick and a ClientId  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675526/clientid-inside-of-ascx-file